# batch file to distribute Access front end

Tags: batch-file, ms-access

I'm trying to create a batch file that will copy Access 2016 front end to the Desk top. I've trying to understand the example below:

```
    @echo Please wait while the version of the database you requested is updated to your desktop.
    @echo off
    @echo %username%
    if not EXIST "C:\MyApplication\Profiles\%username%" GoTo LocalFileFolderWasNotThere
    xcopy /Q /Y "\\MySharePath\MyNetworkFolder\Admin\MyDivision\MyApplication\MyApplication_JohnGault.accdb" "C:\MyApplication\Profiles\%username%\*.*"
    REM TYPE NUL | choice /c:delay /td,5 >NUL
    Start /max "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE15\MSACCESS.EXE" "\\MySharePath\MyNetworkFolder\Admin\MyDivision\MyApplication\Profiles\%username%\MyApplication_JohnGault.accdb" 
    exit
    :LocalFileFolderWasNotThere
    @echo Creating You A New Profile
    MD "C:\MyApplication\Profiles\%username%"
    xcopy /Q /Y "\\MySharePath\MyNetworkFolder\Admin\MyDivision\MyApplication\REgulatory_JohnGault.accdb" "C:\MyApplication\Profiles\%username%\*.*"
REM TYPE NUL | choice /c:delay /td,5 >NUL
Start /max "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE15\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\MyApplication\Profiles\%username%\REgulatory_JohnGault.accdb" 
exit
```

Could someone please explain what is accomplished in the following step?

```
REM TYPE NUL | choice /c:delay /td,5 >NUL

    Start /max "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE15\MSACCESS.EXE" "\\MySharePath\MyNetworkFolder\Admin\MyDivision\MyApplication\Profiles\%username%\MyApplication_JohnGault.accdb" 
    exit
```

Is the code referring to the front/back end of the application here? I assumed that

`\\MySharePath\MyNetworkFolder\Admin\MyDivision\MyApplication\MyApplication_JohnGault.accdb`

was referencing the front end, no?

If someone could explain what's going on in each step, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but an alternative and robust method: [Deploy Access 2007 Database with SQL back end to Citrix for multiple users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097886/deploy-access-2007-database-with-sql-back-end-to-citrix-for-multiple-users/34150736#34150736)

Answer (score 1):

`REM TYPE NUL | choice /c:delay /td,5 >NUL` **does nothing**; it's just **a comment** (read `help rem`):

> ```
> d:\bat> rem /?
> Records comments (remarks) in a batch file or CONFIG.SYS.
>
> REM [comment]
> ```

`TYPE NUL | choice /c:delay /td,5 >NUL` **does nothing**; it returns **error**:

> ```
> d:\bat> TYPE NUL | choice /c:delay /t 5 >NUL
> ERROR: Invalid syntax. /T can be specified only when /D is specified.
> Type "CHOICE /?" for usage.
> ```

`TYPE NUL | choice /c:delay /d d /t 5 >NUL` **does nothing**; although it's syntactically correct it returns **error**:

> ```
> d:\bat> TYPE NUL | choice /c:delay /d d /t 5 >NUL
>
> ERROR: The file is either empty or does not contain the valid choices.
> ```

`choice /c:delay /d d /t 5 >NUL`     **silently waits for 5 seconds** (the time period specified by `/T` parameter value) or until `D`, `E`, `L`, `A` or `Y` is pressed.

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`>NUL` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

**Update** to answer another part of the question about [`start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html):

> Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window.)
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
> ```

above syntax tokens are, in the original code:

- `START` - name of Windows `cmd` internal command.
- `"title"` - missing, **adjusted** below: *Always include a `TITLE` this can be a simple string like `"My Script"` or just a pair of empty quotes `""`. According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other options chosen **you can have problems if it is omitted**.*
- `[/D path]` - **optional**, correctly omitted,
- `[options]` - **/max** forces *opening `MSACCESS.EXE` in a maximized window*,
- `"command"` - fully qualified path to `MSACCESS.EXE` - to ensure that following database file would open in `MSACCESS.EXE` even if it could be associated with another default application,
- `[parameters]` - fully qualified UNC path to an [Access 2007/2010 database file (`.accdb` type)](https://www.lifewire.com/accdb-file-2619459) to be opened using  `MSACCESS.EXE`.

Use the following corrected syntax:

```
Start "" /max "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE15\MSACCESS.EXE" "\\MySharePath\MyNetworkFolder\Admin\MyDivision\MyApplication\Profiles\%username%\MyApplication_JohnGault.accdb"
```

If `MSACCESS.EXE` is currently associated as default application for `.accdb` file type then following command should suffice:

```
Start "" /max "\\MySharePath\MyNetworkFolder\Admin\MyDivision\MyApplication\Profiles\%username%\MyApplication_JohnGault.accdb"
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you please clarify what is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE15\MSACCESS.EXE" "\\MySharePath\MyNetworkFolder\Admin\MyDivision\MyApplication\Profiles\%username%\MyApplication_JohnGault.accdb` referencing, is this the back end?  Why is MSACCESS.EXE needed?

Comment: @user3781528 - It's just opening MyApplication_John‌​Gault.accdb using MSACCESS.EXE and maximizing the window.  You need to supply the full path to the file you're opening, and the application you're using to open it.  The weird thing is, if you're just distributing a back end I have no idea why you'd want to open it.  You should really be distributing a desktop shortcut to go along with the app, and the user can open it when it's done downloading.

Comment: @Johnny Bones. Could you please include an example as an answer?